# python call navigation from another file

Tags: python, tkinter, navigation, frame

how would I perform the navigation to the second page from an event that happens in another python file?
this would be my gui code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import openf

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="first page")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class Page2(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)


        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p1.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    menubar = Menu(root)
    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openf.openfiledialog)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=root.quit)
    filemenu.add_separator()
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    root.config(menu=menubar)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("500x600")
```

I don't need to use buttons for navigation. I want to navigate to the second page when a function is executed successfully in another py file.
I have to import main.py to the other file, but how do I call the frame navigation from there ?

openf.py

```
from tkinter import filedialog

def openfiledialog():
    global of
    of = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=[("archives", "*.zip")])
    openfile())

def openfile():
    with zipfile.ZipFile(of, "r") as f:
    # navigate gui to second page from here
```

Comment: As posted, what you ask is impossible because no GUI will ever be created. The code under `if __name__ == "__main__":` will not be executed when the code is imported.

Comment: Ok. the ideea is this: the menu openfile is referenced in the python file and and it's a function that get's a openfile dialog wich goes to another function that really opens the file. the main file we run is the gui file wich imports some functionality from the second file for the opefiledialog and openfile. so gui is already created. is it impossible to navigate the gui to the second page from within the other file? I will post the complete code once I get home if necessary.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add clarification, instead of burying the information in a comment. And no, it's not impossible. All you need is a reference to the object. How you that depends entirely on how _exactly_ you are creating the object and in what file.

Comment: Done. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: Your code still doesn't work. Is `command=fopen.openfiledialog` actually supposed to be `command=openf.openfiledialog`?

Comment: that is correct. sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the way to "navigate to" one of your pages is to call the `show` method on it. Therefore, all you need is a reference to the page in order to navigate to it.

I recommend creating a method on `MainView` that can be used to navigate to a page. You could then pass a symbolic name in, and it would use that name to determine which page to show.

For example:

```
class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pages = {
            "p1": Page1(self),
            "p2": Page2(self),
        }
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.pages["p1"].place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.pages["p2"].place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.show("p1")

    def show(self, page_name):
        page = self.pages[page_name]
        page.show()
```

Once you've done that, you just have to pass `main` to the function that you want to have navigate to the other page.

For example, start by passing `main` to the `openfiledialog` method of the other file:

```
...
filemenu.add_command(
    label="Open", 
    command=lambda: openf.openfiledialog(main)
)
...
```

And then in `openfiledialog`, use that reference to show the frame:

```
def openfiledialog(main):
    ...
    openfile(main)

def openfile(main):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(of, "r") as f:
        main.show("p1")
```

Comment: still doesn't explain on how to do this from another file. NameError: name 'w' is not defined when I do the show part in function from another file

Comment: @erma86: you haven't shown us how you're using this other file. This is no different than if you need to access an integer or a string in another file -- you simply need a reference to the object. For example, you can make `main` global and then import it into the other file. It depends on exactly how these two files are being used.